# Jenkins not triggering a job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

i am facing an issue with my jenkins server, i tried installing slack plugin on jenkins and ended up facing certain issues which prevent me from triggering a job. Here is the log, can anyone suggest me what might have gone wrong ?

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/avanti-lms-specs/workspace
  FATAL: 
  jenkins.model.Jenkins.getActiveInstance()Ljenkins/model/Jenkins;
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  jenkins.model.Jenkins.getActiveInstance()Ljenkins/model/Jenkins;
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.displayurlapi.DisplayURLProvider.getRoot(DisplayURLProvider.java:44)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.displayurlapi.ClassicDisplayURLProvider.getJobURL(ClassicDisplayURLProvider.java:36)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.displayurlapi.DisplayURLProvider$DisplayURLProviderImpl.getJobURL(DisplayURLProvider.java:88)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.displayurlapi.EnvironmentContributorImpl.buildEnvironmentFor(EnvironmentContributorImpl.java:24)
  at hudson.model.Job.getEnvironment(Job.java:382)
  at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:345)
  at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2248)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:905)
  at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:883)
  at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1253)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
  at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
  at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
  at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
  at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

Comment: In java `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ` means your libs that Jenkins is using aren't compatible with each other. Try to upgrade the jenkins, or find the lowest version of the plugin. If upgrading the Jenkins didn't help you should report the issue to bugtracker.

Comment: @deathangel908 which plugin is being talked about here ? DisplayURLProvider ?

Comment: You said that you tried to install `slack plugin`. Remove other plugins just to check the conflict

Comment: worked, thanks some issue with `displayurlapi` plugin